# Why does a curl GET request with query string parameters require quotes?

Tags: node.js, express

When making a curl GET request from the command line, why are quotes required?

I'm matching to the following route...

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.test);
  res.status(200).send('done');
});
```

...and this matches the route just fine...

```
curl http://localhost:5000/weather
curl "http://localhost:5000/weather?test=testing"
```

This, however, fails to match the route...

```
curl http://localhost:5000/weather?test=testing
```

It returns this error:

> zsh: no matches found: http://localhost:5000/weather?test=testing

I'd like to know why this is the case, but I can't find anything more than people saying quotes are required (or that they are required when an "&" is present in the QSP).

Comment: I do think this depends on OS. Also, what error is returned?

Comment: The `&` has a special meaning to the command line processor (it means different things to Unix and Windows but it is a special character for both of them).  The same is true of `?` and `*`.  And `:`, `,`, and `=` are treated special when it is in a batch file's command line parameters.  Putting the stuff in quotes tells the command line processor not to treat it specially.

Comment: Here is a page describing the Windows command line processor: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Comment: I’m on a Mac and the error I’m getting isn’t really an error, per se. The route just isn’t matching.

Comment: Please share the info you are seeing on your screen (do not let us guess about it....)

Comment: Error = zsh: no matches found: http://localhost:5000/weather?test=testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the question mark "?" is a metacharacter for the command line , it represent a single character, like . in regex, so you need to escape it by putting it between quotes, for example file?.txt could match file1.txt filea.txt ...

Comment: "a metacharacter for the command line", when using `zsh`.

Comment: Just for others to make it clear, either use the entier url within the quote, like: `curl 'http://example.com?q=string'` or escape `?` like `curl http://example.com\?q=string`